# Add UIImageView to custom UIButton class

Tags: ios, uibutton, custom-view

I created a custom UIButton class and overwrote the init Method :

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame title:(NSString *)titulo
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code

        setaDown = [UIImage imageNamed:@"setaDown"];
        separator = [UIImage imageNamed:@"separatorLine"];

        self = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
        [self setFrame:frame];
        self.contentHorizontalAlignment = UIControlContentHorizontalAlignmentLeft;
        self.contentEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 10, 0, 0);
        seta = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(frame.size.width-setaDown.size.width*2, frame.size.height/2, setaDown.size.width/1.2, setaDown.size.height/1.2)];
        [seta setImage:setaDown];
        [self addSubview:seta];
        separatorLine = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(5, frame.size.height-2, frame.size.width-10, separator.size.height)];
        [separatorLine setImage:separator];
        [self addSubview:separatorLine];
        [self setTitle:titulo forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [self setTitleColor:[UIColor blackColor] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
        [self setTitleColor:[UIColor blackColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [self setTitleColor:[UIColor blackColor] forState:UIControlStateSelected];
        self.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    }
    return self;
}
```

The problem is, the images doesnt show in the button, and i have a `exc_bad_access`, in the line :

```
seta = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(frame.size.width-setaDown.size.width*2, frame.size.height/2, setaDown.size.width/1.2, setaDown.size.height/1.2)];
```

dont know exaclty why im getting this error, and how to solve it.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a custom `UIControl`, it has `touchUp event` and put any kind of components on it. If the `UIButton` doesn't meet your need, then you can make a custom `UIControl`.

Ex:

```
class MyButton: UIControl {
   @IBOutlet var myImage: UIImageView!
   @IBOutlet var myTitle: UILabel!
   @IBOutlet var myImage2: UIImageView!


   override var isSelected: Bool {
        didSet {
             // Configure image for `isSelected` status been changed.
             myImage.image = (isSelected ? selImg  : normalImg)
        }
   }       

   override var isEnabled: Bool {
        didSet {
             // Configure for `isEnabled` status been changed.
             myTitle.isEnabled = isEnabled
        }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A `UIButton` already has an `imageView`.  You can simply use

```
self.imageView.image = setaDown
```

and configure other aspects of the `imageView` as needed (for example, position and size so that your `separator` fits).

Comment: i need two more inside it. its two different images.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, you can't add 2 images to a button. Get an image editor, composite them together and then do this:

```
[self setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"mynewimagename"] forState:UIControlStateNormal]
```

Much simpler.

Comment: the problem is the image is relative to the textSize, and supports Landscape and Portrait Orientation.